# Facing Issue while sending mail in java using JavaMail.jar and Activation.jar

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, office365

I am trying to send mail from office 365 mail ID to another in java.I have added mail.jar and activation.jar in the project. but facing following Exception.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Default SSLContext not available
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1907)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:666)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at agent.client.attributeGroups.SendReceive.sendMail(SendReceive.java:75)
    at agent.client.attributeGroups.MailQueue.calculateTime(MailQueue.java:39)
    at agent.client.MainClass.<init>(MainClass.java:59)
    at agent.client.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:152)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Default SSLContext not available
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.a(SSLSocketFactory.java:2)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:7)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:485)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1902)
```

Please help me out to resolve this Exception.

Comment: Please add code to the question

Comment: Properties property = new Properties();
property.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
       property.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
       property.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
       property.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
       property.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
       property.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
           property.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "true");
       property.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtpserver");

Comment: please add it to question instead of comment

Comment: Get rid of all the [socket factory settings](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) and if it still doesn't work post the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).